# Rails ActiveRecord pessimitic locking on reading different records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

To get a better understanding of pessimistic locking, I tried to run this code in my Rails application:

```
Thread.new do
  geoge_order.with_lock do
    puts "[geoge] transaction start"
    sleep(1)
    puts "[geoge] transaction end"
  end
end

Thread.new do
  amanda_order.with_lock do
    puts "[amanda] transaction start"
    puts "[amanda] transaction end"
  end
end
```

I set a pessimistic lock on different order records, so I expected each order to be readable at the same time. And I got what I expected from the Rails console:

```
[geoge] transaction start
[amanda] transaction start
[amanda] transaction end
[geoge] transaction end
```

However, when executed in the Rails test, a read lock occurs as if a lock were set on the same record :

```
[geoge] transaction start
[geoge] transaction end
[amanda] transaction start
[amanda] transaction end
```

Why is the result on the rails console different from the result on the rails test?

- development environment : Ruby 2.6.0, Ruby on Rails 5.2.2, MySql 14.14, Test : Rspec, MiniTest

Comment: I wonder if this could just be a timing difference in the two environments rather than an actual difference in locking behavior.  Is any pessimistic locking behavior even triggered without trying to write to the database?

Comment: In the rails test, I changed the rails's use_transactional_fixtures configuration value to false. Then it works well. I do not know the meaning of the use_transactional_fixtures, so I need to learn. Thank you for your comment.